# How to run sys.sp_addlogin in ant sql task?

Tags: sql, ant, task

I got error 
BUILD FAILED
C:\Projects...\build.xml:987: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The procedure 'sys.sp_addlogin' cannot be executed within a transaction.
How can i make an ant sql task run this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try use CREATE LOGIN instead of sp_addlogin

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well that I tried too but since I couldn't change the SQL script I found a walk around by using executable

```
        <exec executable="sqlcmd" >
            <arg value= "-S"/>
            <arg value= "${ServerName}"/>
            <arg value="-d"/>
            <arg value="DataBaseName"/>
            <arg value="-i"/>
            <arg value="${build.sql}/mssql/script.sql"/>
            <arg value="-E"/>
            <arg value="-b"/>
        </exec>
```